# Need explanation for recursive replace function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Hi I'm very new to javascript programming. I'm learning on FCC and Grasshopper. On Grasshopper, I am stuck on a lesson about recursive replace function. I can not understand it. It will be a great help if someone explains it.
So according to the lesson, it goes like:

```js
var wrongDocument = "This document  ahs a typo in it. The other one ahs typo too.";
function changeSpelling(string, oldPart, newPart) {
  if (string.includes(oldPart) === false) {
    return string;
  }
  string = string.replace(oldPart, newPart);
  return changeSpelling(string, oldPart, newPart);
};
console.log(wrongDocument);
console.log(changeSpelling(wrongDocument, 'ahs', 'has'));
```

The problem I'm facing is that I do not understand why and how can the return statement call for the function that it is nestled in?

Second why this can't be explained with an if...else statement?
Thirdly, I'm having problem to understand parameters and arguments.
So I wrote the following codes. This is definitely not replacing all the spelling, but I can't understand further.

```js
var chat = "This document ahs a typo in it. The other one ahs too.";
var fix = (a, b) => {
    if (chat.includes(a) === false) {
        return chat;
    }
    else {
        return chat.replace(a, b)
    }
}

console.log(chat);
console.log(fix('ahs', 'has'));
```

Please explain how recursive function works and what issues my code have.

Comment: Not sure that this is the place to explain recursion. In addition you have several questions that is hard to explain within the format of stackoverflow

Comment: Just something to get you started: The recursion is similar to writing a `while` loop, rather than an `if` / `else`. `while (string.includes(oldPart)) { string = string.replace(oldPart, newPart); } return string;` would be equivalent to the recursive implementation.

Comment: @Mulli  know. But I can't ask anywhere else. I asked in the respective forums but it will be like a week before someone replies. I can't stall my progress until then. If it can be explained in comments, that's fine too.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you. Let me check that out. Haven't come across it yet.

Comment: Why is recursion needed at all here? There's `.replaceAll`, as well as `new RegExp(oldPart ,"g")` so why would you need to manually search a string?

Comment: @JonasWilms Hmm you see I'm new and I don't know these. The course I'm following didn't introduce those yet. And I don't understand this particular codeblock.

Comment: @JonasWilms JS has no `replaceAll`?

Comment: @JonasWilms: From the code, I was assuming that this lesson was, in fact, intended as a gentle introduction to recursion.  It seems a decent way to do this, even if I take some issue with the actual code presented (never teach a student to mutate a parameter unnecessarily.)  Also `.replaceAll` is still a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replaceall).

Comment: @ScottSauyet I know, but I think a good tutorial would also mention that there are other (better) ways of doing the same thing ... as I suppose it did not, that's why I was doing that ...

Answer (score 3):

> The problem I'm facing is that I do not understand why and how can the return statement call for the function that it is nestled in?

You're right.  This would be a big problem, and recursion would chase its tail forever, except for this bit:

```js
  if (string.includes(oldPart) === false) {
    return string;
  }
```

So the recursive call (`return changeSpelling(string, oldPart, newPart)`) is not the only way to return from the function.  There is also at least one (in this case only one) *base case* that returns without a recursive call.  Moreover, every recursive calls make progress toward a base case, since each time there is one fewer instances of your particular typo.  If these two are true, then a recursive call is well-defined.

Your alternative solution replaces only the first instance of the typo.  This is all it's designed to do.  There are several ways this could be fixed.  Perhaps the most obvious one is to wrap up your code inside a `while` loop as in the following:

```js
const fix = (chat, a, b) => {
  if (chat .includes (a) === false) {
    return chat;
  }
  else {
    return chat.replace(a, b)
  }
}

const fixAll = (chat, a, b) => {
  let test = chat
  while (test .includes (a)) {
    test = fix (test, a, b)
  }
  return test
}

const chat = "This document ahs a typo in it. The other one ahs too.";

console .log (chat)
console .log (fixAll (chat, 'ahs', 'has'))
```

(Note that I'm now passing the string into the function.  This makes for code that's easier to understand and to test, using only its parameters and doing nothing else besides returning a value.  That's the definition of a pure function.  You will find that pure functions have a lot of advantages.)

But there's some real redundancy in that.  There is no good reason we check twice that the string is included.  This can be cleaned up by inlining the relevant work from `fix` into `fixAll`:

```js
const fixAll = (chat, a, b) => {
  let test = chat
  while (test .includes (a)) {
    test = test .replace (a, b)
  }
  return test
}

const chat = "This document ahs a typo in it. The other one ahs too.";

console .log (chat)
console .log (fixAll (chat, 'ahs', 'has'))
```

This is a perfectly reasonable way to solve this problem.  Presumably your lesson is about teaching you an alternative technique, one of using recursion to solve problems.  So let's start again.

> Q: What are we trying to do?
>
> A: Replace all occurrences of the typo with the correct string.
>
> Q: How should we do that?
>
> A: What do you mean?
>
> Q: Well, what should we do first?
>
> A: Replace the first one, I guess.
>
> Q: And how do we do that?
>
> A: `string .replace (oldPart, newPart)`
>
> Q: And what's next?
>
> A: Well, then we replace the second one.
>
> Q: How?
>
> A: The same way, `string .replace (oldPart, newPart)`
>
> Q: And then what?
>
> A: The third one, the same way.
>
> Q: And then what?
>
> A: Well, we keep doing this until there are no more misspellings.
>
> Q: And how do we know that there are none?
>
> A: We check with `string .includes (oldPart)`
>
> Q: When do we do this test?
>
> A: Before the replacement.
>
> Q: Every time?
>
> A: Yes.
>
> Q: Okay, then.  Can you write this down as an explicit set of instructions?
>
> A: Here goes
>
> ```
> 1. Check if the string has any misspellings
> 2. If not, return it as is
> 3. If so, replace it with the good string
> 4. Go back to step 1.
> ```
>
> Q: It's looking good.  But when you return to step 1, what string are you using to test?
>
> A: The one in which we just replaced the misspelled word with the correct one.
>
> Q: So how would we write this as a function?
>
> A: How about this?
>
> ```js
> const changeSpelling = (string, oldPart, newPart) => {
>   if (!string .includes (oldPart)) {
>     return string
>   }
>   string.replace (oldPart, newPart)
>   // hmm, do it again here.  But how?
> }
> ```
>
> Q: Yes.  Now you want to do it again.  You already have a function to do that; it's what you're writing.  Can't we just call it?
>
> A: But it's incomplete.
>
> Q: And this step will complete it.  What would it look like to call the function again here?
>
> A: I suppose something like this:
>
> ```js
> const changeSpelling = (string, oldPart, newPart) => {
>   if (!string .includes (oldPart)) {
>     return string
>   }
>   string .replace (oldPart, newPart)
>   changeSpelling (string, oldPart, newPart)
> }
> ```
>
> Q: It's getting closer, but what do we return at the end?
>
> A: Oh right, it should be `return changeSpelling (string, oldPart, newPart)`.
>
> Q: Correct, but what string should we be passing to it?
>
> A: The one we just changed.
>
> Q: Yes, but `.replace` doesn't alter your string, it creates a new one with the replacement included.
>
> A: Oh, so we need to save that changed string.  How's this?
>
> ```js
> const changeSpelling = (string, oldPart, newPart) => {
>   if (string .includes (oldPart) === false) {
>     return string
>   }
>   const newString = string .replace (oldPart, newPart)
>   return changeSpelling (newString, oldPart, newPart)
> }
> ```
>
> Q: That looks good.  Does it follow the rules of recursion we mentioned?
>
> A: Well, it has at least one base case.  What was the other rule?
>
> Q: The recursive case must make progress towards one of your base cases.
>
> A: Right, and since we've replaced one of the typos, we're moving toward the case where there are none left.  So yes.
>
> Q: I think it will work.  Are you happy with it?
>
> A: I think so.  Is this how you would do it?
>
> Q: Well, I'm a real fan of using expressions rather than control statements, and of not assigning unnecessary temporary variables, so mine would look a bit different.  But the basic idea would be the same.
>
> A: Can you show me how you would do it?
>
> Q: Sure, mine would look more like this:
>
> ```
> const changeSpelling = (oldPart, newPart) => (string) =>
>   string .includes (oldPart)
>     ? changeSpelling (oldPart, newPart) (string .replace (oldPart, newPart))
>     : string
> ```
>
> A: That looks very different.  Why do you say it's the same?
>
> Q: I think that's a lesson for another day.

Comment: Loving the `Q/A`-style! I'm going to use that sometime. And great answer btw, you saved me from having to write an answer :)

Comment: @Thankyou: Anything to help!

Comment: This is one of those interesting cases where you can replace `a ? b : c` with `a && b || c`. Not suggesting it's an improvement btw, just fascinating...

Comment: @Thankyou: Yes it is, but I've pretty well stopped using that.  I find the explicit conditional operator easier to comprehend, even if it's only a matter of how to layout the punctuation.

Comment: @Thankyou.  I do use something like that in two Ramda functions, `when`, and `otherwise`, which are both glosses on `ifElse :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b)`, which replace either of the last two parameters with `identity`.  It is useful, but the `&& - ||` syntax simply feels too obscure.